# How Do create insert query using procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

**How Do create insert query using procedure**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insert_emp `()
INSERT INTO employee(id,name,salary,address) VALUES (id,name,salary,address)

$name= $_POST['name'];
$salary= $_POST['salary'];
$address= $_POST['address'];

$sql=mysql_query("CALL insert_emp ($name,$salary,$address)");
```

Comment: Please tag dbms used! (Doesn't look like ANSI SQL...)'

Comment: What means `not working`?

Comment: how to set working call procedure using this query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the field "id" is set to auto-increment inorder to have an easy inserting into table.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
/*[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]*/
PROCEDURE `insert_emp`(IN NAME VARCHAR(15),IN salary INT,IN address VARCHAR(15))

BEGIN
INSERT INTO `employee`(employee.`id`,employee.`name`,employee.`salary`,employee.`address`) VALUES (id,NAME,salary,address);
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Example query,
CALL `insert_emp`('anish',18000,'mlre');